# KnpPaginator not works on joined tables

Tags: symfony4, knppaginator

I'm trying to get two tables joined and get a sorted result set from KnpPaginator. Here is my code.

View

```twig
<table class="table table-bordered">
       <tr>
            <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Id', 'c.id') }}</th>
            <th{% if pagination.isSorted('c.name') %} class="sorted"{% endif %}>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Name', 'c.name') }}</th>
            <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Version', 'c.model.name') }}</th>
       </tr>
       {% for article in pagination %}
           <tr {% if loop.index is odd %}class="color"{% endif %}>
               <td>{{ article.id }}</td>
               <td>{{ article.getName }}</td>
               <td>{{ article.model.name }}</td>
           </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Controller

```php
$em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $dql = "SELECT c FROM App\Entity\Car c";
        $query = $em->createQuery($dql);

        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
                $query, /* query NOT result */ $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/* page number */, 10/* limit per page */
        );
```

Model model

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ModelRepository")
 */
class Model
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
```

Car model

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CarRepository")
 */
class Car
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Model",cascade={"refresh","merge"}, inversedBy="cars")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $model;

    public function getModel(): ?Model
    {
        return $this->model;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setModel(?Model $model): self
    {
        $this->model = $model;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

When I get article.model.name inside table body it works. But `knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Version', 'c.model.name')` only show this error

> There is no such field [model.name] in the given Query component,
> aliased by [c]

I have removed some unwanted code for better visibility. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution.

```php
    $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    
    $query = $qb->select('c', 'm')
            ->from('App\Entity\Car', 'c')
            ->leftJoin('c.model', 'm')
            ->getQuery();

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $query, /* query NOT result */ $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/* page number */, 10/* limit per page */
    );
```

But you need relationships correctly added to work this Here I have added,

```php
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Model",cascade={"refresh","merge"}, inversedBy="cars")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $model;

    public function getModel(): ?Model
    {
        return $this->model;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setModel(?Model $model): self
    {
        $this->model = $model;

        return $this;
    }
```